# Parsing a string by using a defined delimiter

Tags: c++, string

I made a function which must return a vector of strings even when the delimiter is repeating. This is what I have for now:

```
std::vector<std::string> stringParse(const std::string &s, char delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string token="";

    std::string delimiterToString="";
    delimiterToString+=delimiter;

    while (getline(ss, token, delimiter)) {
        if(token != delimiterToString)
            result.push_back(token);
    }


    return result;
}
```

I need to set the delimiter to a whitespace and extract the words from:

```
"test                    test1                     test2"
```

but the final vector contains the whitespaces even after I've applied the condition: `if(token != delimiterToString)`

I'm not very good at c++ so I'm sorry if this question has a obvious answer but I really can't see where is the impediment.

Comment: I expect `getline` to produce an empty string, not a string containing the delimiter. Try `if (!token.empty()) ...`

Comment: `std::string token="";` and `std::string token;` are essentially the same thing since you want an empty string. Save yourself some typing.

Comment: While @IgorTandetnik has provided you with the solution, I recommend you use that very simple code to get used to your debugging tools. You could, for instance, put a breakpoint on the `if (...)` line and check the content of `token` at each loop. This is a skill you will definitely need.

Comment: *"I made a function which must return a vector of strings even when the delimiter is repeating."* -- This is not a good description of your situation. I can easily fulfill these functional requirements with `std::vector<std::string> stringParse(const std::string &s, char delimiter) { return {}; }`. *Write out what you are doing; don't assume everyone knows your goal.*

Comment: *"even after I've applied the condition: `if(token != delimiterToString)`"* -- This looks like an invitation to test this condition specifically. What are `token` and `delimiterToString` when this condition is checked? (A line like `std::cout << "Token: |" << token << "|\ndelimiterToString = |" << delimiterToString <<"|\n";` before the `if` might help answer this.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be solved if you change

```cpp
if(token != delimiterToString)
```

to

```cpp
if (!token.empty())
```

`std::getline` never adds the delimiter to the result string.
If there are multiple consecutive delimiters, you simply get empty strings.

For example, `std::getline` for

```
test                    test1                     test2
```

with a delimiter `' '` would yield

```cpp
"test", "", "", "", ..., "test1", "", ..., "test"
```

### More minimal solution (C++11)

Using `std::stringstream` just to split a string into parts could be considered a bit excessive.
A more minimal solution is:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> stringParse(const std::string &s, char delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    if (s.empty()) return result;

    const char delimiter_str[2] {delimiter, '\0'};

    std::size_t pos = 0;
    while (pos != std::string::npos) {
        std::size_t end = s.find(delimiter, pos);
        if (end == std::string::npos) {
            result.push_back(s.substr(pos));
            break;
        }
        result.push_back(s.substr(pos, end - pos));
        pos = s.find_first_not_of(delimiter_str, end + 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

`delimiter_str` is an ugly workaround.
It lets us use `std::string::find_first_not_of` as an alternative to a hypothetical `std::string::find_not`.

In C++17, all uses of `std::string` can and should be replaced with `std::string_view` in this code.

### More minimal solution (C++23)

```cpp
auto words = str
           | std::views::split(std::string_view(" "))
           | std::views::filter([](auto subrange) { return !subrange.empty(); });
for (const auto subrange : words) {
    std::cout << std::string_view(subrange) << '\n';
}
```

See also [How do I iterate over the words of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/5740428)